# AWS SDK php S3 refuses to access bucketname xxx.mydomain.com

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use AWS S3 to store image files for my website. I create a bucket name  images.mydomain.com which was referred by dns cname  images.mydomain.com from AWS Route 53.

I want to check whether a folder or file exists; if not I will create one.
The following php codes work fine for regular bucket name using stream wrapper but fails for this type of bucket name such as  xxxx.mydomain.com.   This kind of bucket name fails in doesObjectExist() method too.

```
// $new_dir = "s3://aaaa/akak3/kk1/yy3/ww4" ;   //  this line works ! 

$new_dir = "s3://images.mydomain.com/us000000/10000" ;   // this line fails ! 

if( !file_exists( $new_dir) ){
   if( !mkdir( $new_dir , 0777 , true ) ) {
         echo "create new dir  $new_dir failed ! <br>" ;
   } else { 
        echo "SUCCEED in creating  new dir $new_dir <br" ; 
   }
} else { 
  echo "dir $new_dir already exists. Skip creating dir ! <br>" ;  
}
```

I got the following message

Warning: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint: "images.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com". in C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\S3\StreamWrapper.php on line 737

What is the problem here?
Any advise on what to do for this case?
Thanks!

Comment: What regions are these two buckets in?

Comment: us-west-2 .  Why does it matter?

Comment: It sounds like the error is telling you that your client is connecting to the wrong region. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/configuration.html#specify-region